# What are the limitations of synthesized Selenium events on Firefox?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The [Selenium 2.45 changelog](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) says:

> Native events in Firefox relied on an API that Mozilla no longer
>   provides. As such, fall back to synthesized events on recent Firefox
>   versions.

While I ([and others](https://bugs.launchpad.net/selenium-simple-test/+bug/1242364)) have experienced problems with the frequent breaking of native events in Firefox, I also remember problems when falling back to non-native events when using Actions.moveByOffset() and friends.  In particular, events going to the wrong element and drags failing.

What are the limitations of synthesized events on Firefox?  Has it been improving?

Comment: Another option is to switch to Chrome, as it supports native events: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Native_events_versus_synthetic_events

Comment: @Yoshi That's not an option. Even though there are standards, browsers don't behave the same. Something that works on Chrome won't work on FF because the FF devs decided to do something differently, and vice-versa. Eliminating a browser from the test runs will just hide the problem.

Comment: Good question but I don't think anyone, but a select few, know the real answer.

Comment: I also curious about the answer to this question, especially in light of the new Marionette project.